# False links on homepage only on mobile devices (not viewport, only mobile devices)

Tags: wordpress, elementor, mobile-browser

EDIT: This appears to happen to EVERY link on the page!

I am encountering a specific issue on a WordPress website where all links in the footer are generated with the syntax "{{{{{A-HREF-#}}}}" (where # represents a number). This issue happens only on mobile devices (not viewport-width related, only real mobile devices)

I have constructed the pages and footer section using Elementor, and all footer links are generated with the "{{A-HREF-#}}" syntax.

This specific footer is embedded into every page and was created in the "Theme Elementor Sections" section (so no custom html code).

It happens on both android and ios so far.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with Elementor or the "{{{{A-HREF-#}}}}" syntax for footer links? Does anyone have insights into what might be causing this discrepancy in link generation specifically on mobile devices? Any help or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code from the Desktop Browser Developer Tools

```
<ul class="elementor-icon-list-items elementor-inline-items">
<li class="elementor-icon-list-item elementor-inline-item">

<a href="/datenschutz">

<span class="elementor-icon-list-text">Datenschutzerklärung</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the code from the Mobile Browser Developer Tools

```
<ul class="elementor-icon-list-items elementor-inline-items">
<li class="elementor-icon-list-item elementor-inline-item">

<a href="{{{{A-HREF-36}}}}">

<span class="elementor-icon-list-text">Datenschutzerklärung</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Clearing the browser cache on mobile devices did not resolve the issue.

I have updated all plugins and WordPress to their latest versions.
I inspected Elementor to verify if the link is set differently in responsive editing mode — it is not.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question. It will help you state you question better and make it easier for others to answer. For example provide your code in codeblocks and not within images.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with wordpress, I know only pretty basic stuff.

If I can give you more details I'm glad to do so (if it's not common sense to get those details, maybe explain how I can give you those informations too :D)

Comment: I would start with reading the article I sent you first as there's some useful information over there, and about your question it would be great if you use code blocks and put your code inside of it (start a codeblock with ``` and end it with ``` )

Comment: @Mootje Ohhh, my bad. The first comment seemed like it was an auto-generated message so I didn't pay too much attention to it. Got it!